Attempting to group data frame by string and integer variable but the sum function gives odd results in the integer column
I am using a space mission launches csv to visualize the space race from the 100 days of code course on Udemy. The data table has an organization column that has the names of the different space organizations and a price column that shows how much they spent on each launch.
I used this code to attempt and group the different organizations with the amount they spent while filtering out the organizations with either 0 value or no data.
total_spent_by_org = df_data.groupby('Organisation')['Price'].sum()
total_spent_by_org[total_spent_by_org!=0]
I expected the result to come back with the organizations in one column and the total price they spent in the other column.
This was my result:
Arianespace 48.5200.048.5200.0200.0200.037.0200.037.0200.0...
Boeing          133.0164.0164.0350.0133.0133.0164.0
CASC            29.7564.6829.1529.7564.6829.1529.7530.829.755....
EER         20.0
ESA         37.0
Eurockot    41.841.841.841.841.841.841.841.841.841.841.841...
ExPace          28.3
ILS         65.065.065.065.065.0115.0153.0109.0130.0135.01...
ISRO            21.031.062.021.021.047.021.062.021.031.047.031...
JAXA            90.039.039.0
Kosmotras   29.029.029.029.029.029.029.029.029.029.029.029...
Lockheed    35.035.035.035.035.035.035.035.0
MHI         112.590.0112.590.0112.590.090.090.090.090.090....
Martin Marietta 35.035.0136.635.0136.6136.6136.635.035.0
NASA            450.0450.0450.0450.0450.0450.0450.0450.0450.04...
Northrop    46.085.085.040.085.085.085.085.045.046.040.085...
RVSN USSR   5,000.05,000.0
Rocket Lab  7.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.57.5
Roscosmos   65.048.548.548.565.048.548.565.048.565.065.048...
Sandia          15.0
SpaceX          50.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050.050...
ULA         145.0120.0153.0115.0164.0153.0350.0153.0350.01...
US Air Force    59.059.059.059.059.059.059.059.059.059.059.059...
VKS RF          48.541.848.548.541.848.565.041.848.565.035.065...
Virgin Orbit    12.0

I am unsure of what is causing all of the excess digits in decimals in most of the price column.

If you use a library that provides dataframe implementation (e.g. pandas), add a tag for it. Other way around I don't see anything regarding visualization in your question.

Probably the numbers are stored as string. Therefore the summation becomes a concatenation of these strings. Try to find out how to convert the strings to numbers.
